# Bootstrap - move to part of webpage when button is clicked

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a webpage called index.html and I would like to be able to click on a button and move on a specific part of the webpage (where a form is located). The code I have looks like this:

1. Button:

   ```
   <div href="#button1" class="col-4 align-self-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">
                            Reserve Table
                        </button>
    </div>
   ```
2. Part where I want to go to when button is clicked:

   ```
    <div class="row row-content">
        <div class="col-sm-8 offset-md-2">
            <div class="card" id="card1">
                <h3 class="card-header bg-warning text-white">Reserve a Table</h3>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <dl class="row">
                        <dt class="col-2">Number of Guests</dt>
                        <dd class="col-6"><div class="form-check form-check-inline" id="form1">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">1</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">2</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">3</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio4" value="option4">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio4">4</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio5" value="option5">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio5">5</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio6" value="option6">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio6">6</label>
                          </div></dd>
                          </dl>
                          <dl class="row">
                            <dt class="col-2">Date and Time</dt>
                            <dd class="col-6"><div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label for="telnum" class="col-form-label"></label>
                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <input class="form-control" type="tel" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio6" value="Date">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio6"></label>
                            </div>

                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="tel" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio6" value="Time">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio6"></label>
                                </div>       
                            </dd>            
                        </div>
                        </dd>   
                    </dl>                                                                                  
                    </dl>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="offset-md-2 col-md-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="button1">
                                Reserve
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

             </form>
         </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md">
         </div>
    </div>
   ```

How can I set the ID correctly in order for when the button is pushed I will be going to the form part of the .html page?

I tried setting an ID and using the href command but it is not working!

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Use the validator for that list of errors and fix those first.

Comment: How do I do that? I am not familiar with the "validator".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div>` tag doesn't have `href` attribute. use hyperlink instead. Use a valid id for from tag and use the same id for `href` attribute of the hyperlink

```html
<a href="#form1" class="col-4 align-self-center">  
    Reserve Table
</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<form id="form1">
  <div class="row row-content">
    <div class="col-sm-8 offset-md-2">
      <div class="card" id="card1">
        <h3 class="card-header bg-warning text-white">Reserve a Table</h3>
        <div class="card-body">
          <dl class="row">
            <dt class="col-2">Number of Guests</dt>
            <dd class="col-6">
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline" id="form1">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">1</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">2</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">3</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio4" value="option4">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio4">4</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio5" value="option5">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio5">5</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio6" value="option6">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio6">6</label>
              </div>
            </dd>
          </dl>
          <dl class="row">
            <dt class="col-2">Date and Time</dt>
            <dd class="col-6">
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <label for="telnum" class="col-form-label"></label>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input class="form-control" type="tel" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio6" value="Date">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio6"></label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input class="form-control" type="tel" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio6" value="Time">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio6"></label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </dd>
          </dl>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="offset-md-2 col-md-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="button1">
            Reserve
          </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: I want the reference to be made in the click of the button. Is it so in your code?

Comment: not clear enough on this comment